# Jsoup select parent of direct child

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to select elements with the `<p>` tag as direct child.

I've tried using the following

```
*:has(p)
```

But it doesn't return the direct parents.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Element.parent()`, which will get the parent of the element.

```
String html = "<div> Blah <p> However </p> </div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Element p = doc.select("p").first();

String myText = p.parent().text();  //selects the enclosing div, and gets all the text in the div.

System.out.println(myText);
```

Prints:

```
Blah However
```

AFAIK, there is no selector for parent, so you probably have to go with th `parent()` method.

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
*:has(>p)
```

worked quite well.

`*:has(p)` Would select the whole parent tree, because every parent has the `<p>`. But `*:has(>p)` says, that the element must have a `<p>` as direct child.